# Best simulation method in the case of completely specified distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, simulation, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f$ be a probability density function of the form
$$
f(x)=k \times g(x),
$$
where $k$ is the normalizing constant, $g(x)$ is the kernel of the distribution, that is the part which involves $x$, $g(x)$ typically is not simple, in the sense that integrals involving it are not analytically treatable.

There are many approximate methods for simulating from such a probability distribution, most of them requires only the kernel of the distribution: acceptance-rejection, metropolis-hastings, etc.

My question:

But, if I know $k$, which method(s) would be the most (time) efficient to generate random number from $f$?

For example, from acceptance-rejection and metropolis-hastings perspective, knowing $k$ makes no difference. A more straightforward approach that would take advantage of $k$ would be the inverse transform sampling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), however if $g(x)$ is complicate we will not be able to find the corresponding cdf $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ or, even if we can, the inversion might no be possible, so this method is off of the table(?).

Any other method that would take advantage of this situation? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know $k$ then the quantile function approach is workable, at least numerically, provided the dimension is low enough. The brilliance of a lot of these other methods is that the dependence on the normalization constant cancels out in the way they're set up, so you don't need to know what it is.

Comment: Can you give some reference of some specific numerical method for quantile function? Thanks

Comment: In 1D you can do it yourself easily enough. Pick your favorite numerical integration method, use it to build a CDF lookup table, do binary search to find the bracket of the given random number within the table, then use your favorite interpolant to actually finish the evaluation. (Or you can skip that last step, if your table is big enough.)